# MPI signal handling

Tags: python, signals, mpi

When using `mpirun`, is it possible to catch signals (for example, the SIGINT generated by `^C`) in the code being run?

For example, I'm running a parallelized python code. I can `except KeyboardInterrupt` to catch those errors when running `python blah.py` by itself, but I can't when doing `mpirun -np 1 python blah.py`.

<s>Does anyone have a suggestion? Even finding how to catch signals in a C or C++ compiled program would be a helpful start.</s>

If I send a signal to the spawned Python processes, they can handle the signals properly; however, signals sent to the parent `orterun` process (i.e. from exceeding wall time on a cluster, or pressing control-C in a terminal) will kill everything immediately.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is really implementation dependent.

- In SLURM, I tried to use `sbatch --signal USR1@30` to send `SIGUSR1` (whose signum is 30,10 or 16) to the program launched by `srun` commands. And the process received signal `SIGUSR1 = 10`.
- For platform MPI of IBM, according to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSF4ZA_9.1.4/pmpi_guide/signal_propagation.html

`SIGINT, SIGUSR1, SIGUSR2` will be bypassed to processes.

- In MPICH, SIGUSR1 is used by the process manager for internal notification of abnormal failures.
  ref: http://lists.mpich.org/pipermail/discuss/2014-October/003242.html>
- Open MPI on the other had will forward SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 from mpiexec to the other processes.
  ref: http://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v1.6/man1/mpirun.1.php#sect14>
- For IntelMPI, according to https://software.intel.com/en-us/mpi-developer-reference-linux-hydra-environment-variables

`I_MPI_JOB_SIGNAL_PROPAGATION` and `I_MPI_JOB_TIMEOUT_SIGNAL` can be set to send signal.

Another thing worth notice: For many python scripts, they will invoke other library or codes through cython, and if the `SIGUSR1` is caught by the sub-process, something unwanted might happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `mpirun --nw`, then `mpirun` itself should terminate as soon as it's started the subprocesses, instead of waiting for their termination; if that's acceptable then I believe your processes would be able to catch their own signals.

Comment: For some reason, this argument isn't being recognized by mpirun on my mac (even though it shows up in `man`). `mpirun -n 2 --nw  python test.py` gives the error: `Failed to find the following executable: Executable: --nw`, and I've tried different arrangements of the args and tried `-nw` instead as well. Any idea what's up? Thanks.

Comment: Per http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=osx#osx-bundled-ompi it looks like osx-bundled MPI may not be the best -- this one looks like a bug for example. I'd try their advice, e.g. with http://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.2/downloads/openmpi-1.2.4.dmg.gz first to see if it fixes the bug, else go with http://openmpi.darwinports.com/ , etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it looks like using this option still doesn't allow the running process to accept signals; it puts the processes in the background, just as if I'd run `program &`.

Comment: But now the problem as you stated it ("will die when I hit control-C or when I send ortedrun a signal") disappears: there's no ortedrun you might accidentally signal nor would ^C hurt any of your processes any more, right? So if your problem is something else you should maybe edit and clarify the question. No more than 1 process can be the foreground one in any terminal so that can't be what you're asking, can it?

Answer (score -2):

The [signal](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#module-signal) module supports setting signal handlers using `signal.signal`:

> Set the handler for signal signalnum to the function handler. handler can be a callable Python object taking two arguments (see below), or one of the special values signal.SIG_IGN or signal.SIG_DFL. The previous signal handler will be returned ...

```
import signal
def ignore(sig, stack):
  print "I'm ignoring signal %d" % (sig, )

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ignore)
while True: pass
```

If you send a `SIGINT` to a Python interpreter running this script (via `kill -INT <pid>`), it will print a message and simply continue to run.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't really answer my question. I didn't want to know how to intercept signals in Python; I wanted to know how to prevent `mpirun` from catching them first, or how to pass them from the runner (`orted` or `ortedrun`). When executing `mpirun -np 1 python test.py`, it still will die when I hit control-C or when I send ortedrun a signal. (If I do find the pid of the Python interpreter that ortedrun spawns and signal that, this works; but this isn't really what I want.)